# Problem with regex again

Tags: c#, regex

Let say that i have this to url's

```
site.com/hello-world/test.html
site.com/hello-world/test/test.html
```

if i go to the first url i have this regex

```
^.*/([a-z0-9,-]+)/([a-z0-9,-]+).html$
```

but url 2 is also vaild url with the regex? how to tell the regex that the first url is the url who should be vaild and not the second?

Comment: To answer that, you have to tell us why the first URL is valid and not the second.

Comment: There are infinite solutions, what is the regex logic you want to build?

Comment: Yup - trivial solution would be the regex `^site\.com/hello-world/test\.html$`. It matches the first but not the second URL.

Comment: And to be pedantic, without a scheme such as `http://` or `https:` these are not URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course the second string it is also valid against your regex:

```
sub-expression        result
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
^.*                   matches:   "site.com/hello-world/test/test.html"
/                     backtrack: "site.com/hello-world/test/"
([a-z0-9,-]+)         matches:   "site.com/hello-world/test/test" 
/                     backtrack: "site.com/hello-world/test/"
([a-z0-9,-]+).html$   matches:   "site.com/hello-world/test/test.html"
```

better:

```
sub-expression        result
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
^[^/]+                matches:   "site.com"
/                     matches:   "site.com/"
([a-z0-9,-]+)         matches:   "site.com/hello-world" 
/                     matches:   "site.com/hello-world/"
([a-z0-9,-]+)\.html$  fails (which is the expected result)
```

So you should use:

```
^[^/]+/([a-z0-9,-]+)/([a-z0-9,-]+)\.html$
```

Comment: ^[^/]./([a-z0-9,-]+)/([a-z0-9,-]+).html$ fails?

Comment: That is what you seem to want - the second string should not match, in regex terms that is "the regex fails for this string".

Answer (score 1):

For the first URL the .* part of the pattern matches "site.com", but for the second URL it matches "site.com/hello-world".

If you don't want to allow more than one folder, you can disallow slash characters in the part of the pattern that matches the domain name:

```
^[^/]*/([a-z0-9,-]+)/([a-z0-9,-]+)\.html$
```

(Note that I put a backslash before the period before the html extension. A period matches any character, while `\.` matches only a period.)

Edit:
If you want to allow both URLs and use "hello-world/test" as folder for the second one, allow slashes in the folder part:

```
^[^/]*/([a-z0-9,-/]+)/([a-z0-9,-]+)\.html$
```

If you want to use "hello-world" as folder and "test/test" as page, allow slashes in the file name part:

```
^[^/]*/([a-z0-9,-]+)/([a-z0-9,-/]+)\.html$
```

Comment: i want to allow site.com/hello-world/test.html and site.com/hello-world/test/test.html

but the are to different pages.

Comment: @Frozzare: You specifially asked that the second url should not be valid... I added some alternatives in the answer.

Comment: @Frozzare: I don't understand what you want, you seem to contradict yourself over and over... I have given you alternatives both for matching only the first URL and for matching both URLs, something should match your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the use of the greedy match-all .* at the beginning of your expression.

Cheat a little:

```
^.*(com|org|edu|net|gov)/([a-z0-9,-]+)/([a-z0-9,-]+).html$
```

Answer (score 0):

.* matches "site.com/hello-world" in the second case. You have to be more specific for the domain part.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, .* is matching more than you would expect.

Perhaps replace it with the non-greedy quantifier:

```
^.*?/([a-z0-9,-]+)/([a-z0-9,-]+).html$
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, just a suggestion: there are lots of excellent tools that allow you to experiment with regular expressions and actually help you writing them.
I'm particularly fond of [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm); apparently also [The Regulator](http://osherove.com/tools) is a very good one.